# How can I add custom button in the kendo's editor for SPFx react project?

Tags: spfx, react, kendo

We will use below kendo code to add custom button, this custom button will use to upload document to one drive location::

```
<Editor
           tools={[
                [Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough]
            ]}
            contentStyle={{ height: 300 }}
            onMount={this.state.onBlur}
            defaultContent={this.state.value}
How can I add custom button in the kendo's editor of SPFx react project?
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello RajeshSharepointGeek,

Please check below example:

**Step 1: Install NPM Package**

npm install --save @progress/kendo-react-buttons

**Step 2: Import CSS and Button in tsx file**

[image]

**Step 3: Add button in Render method like this:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

You can refer below link for more details:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/buttons/

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati